# MVC sitemap provider & css styling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

Does anyone know how to customise the rendering of the MVC sitemap provider so my ul element has a specific css class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [MvcSiteMapProvider](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) hosted on CodePlex. You should be able to fairly easily migrate your existing Sitemap file to the slightly different but essentially compatible format.  This will give you the ability to output your sitemap using the simple `Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap()` helper method.

The source of the project includes the default templates which you can edit to produce any rendering you like...or just pass in the name of a template in accordance with MVC convention.  The model types you'll be rendering are `SiteMapHelperModel`, `SiteMapNodeModel` and `SiteMapNodeModelList` (namespaces removed for terseness).

I appreciate this may not be exactly what you're after as it relies on a 3rd party tool but its a useful project that supports much more than just rendering sitemaps. You'll want version 3.0.0 for MVC3.

Dan

Comment: Great, thanks. The sample has a DefaultTemplates folder which contains all the partial output for the sitemaps. I just added this to my project along with the MVCSiteMap library.